# replacing values in shell script using sed

Tags: shell, awk, sed

My shell script looks like this:

```
FAILED_REQUEST_DIRECTORY=/bla/bla2 java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1234  -jar /xyz/abc-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=1111 --server.address=127.0.0.1 --kafka.bootstrap.servers=10.111.11.11:3197,10.112.12.111:3197,10.123.44.25:3197 --topic.pushcrew.encryptionKey=abc-def-egh --spring.application.name=name-sevice  --fb.verification.token=token --management.trace.include.payload=true --topic.pushcrew.hits=activity-logs --max.block.ms=1000 --pager.duty.api.key=apikey --dsn=dsn
```

If I have to replace values of keys in the command, for ex: replacing value of key `--server.address` with the value to shell script through a variable, how would I do it?

I understand it would look like following if I had to replace value for key --server.address:

```
sed -i "s#--server.address=.* #$SERVER_ADDRESS#g;
```

But how do I maintain the space that has to be there after the replacement and how do I make sure that part int the key only after `=`(equals to) and before   (space) gets replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed` with 2 capturing groups and back-references:

```
val='10.0.0.1'

sed -E "s/^(.*--server.address=)[^[:blank:]]+(.*)$/\1$val\2/" file.properties
```

#### Details:

**RegEx:**

- `^(.*--server.address=)`: Match everything at start till `--server.address=` substring and capture in group #1
- `[^[:blank:]]*`: Match 0 or more non-space characters
- `(.*)$`:  Match everything till and end and capture in group #2

**Replacement:**

- `\1`: Back-reference to capture group #1
- `$val`: Place desired `$val` in replacement
- `\2: Back-reference to capture group #2

> `FAILED_REQUEST_DIRECTORY=/bla/bla2 java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1234  -jar /xyz/abc-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=1111 --server.address=10.0.0.1 --kafka.bootstrap.servers=10.111.11.11:3197,10.112.12.111:3197,10.123.44.25:3197 --topic.pushcrew.encryptionKey=abc-def-egh --spring.application.name=name-sevice  --fb.verification.token=token --management.trace.include.payload=true --topic.pushcrew.hits=activity-logs --max.block.ms=1000 --pager.duty.api.key=apikey --dsn=dsn`

Comment: Thanks. I shall replace sed -i with sed -e? I understand -i is in place, what's -E for? Also, would you mind explaining what's exactly happening in the command?

Comment: I just added full explanation. To save changes inline use: **`sed -i -E "s/^(.*--server.address=)[^[:blank:]]+(.*)$/\1$val\2/" file.properties`**

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error though: SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [sed -i  "s/^(.*--server.port=)[^[:blank:]]+(.*)$/\18081\2/" /opt/run-cipher-jenkins.sh] ...
sed: -e expression #1, char 49: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: You cannot remove `-E` option which is used for extended regex.

Comment: If I add -E, I get an error: sed: couldn't open temporary file /opt/sedX3MxFS: Permission denied
I am running this from jenkins and opt folder's owner is jenkins user

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following.(to save output into Input_file itself append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file` to following code)

```
val='10.0.0.1'
awk -v var="$val" '
match($0,/--server\.address=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/=.*/,"="var,val)
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
1
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
FAILED_REQUEST_DIRECTORY=/bla/bla2 java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1234  -jar /xyz/abc-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=1111 --server.address=10.0.0.1 --kafka.bootstrap.servers=10.111.11.11:3197,10.112.12.111:3197,10.123.44.25:3197 --topic.pushcrew.encryptionKey=abc-def-egh --spring.application.name=name-sevice  --fb.verification.token=token --management.trace.include.payload=true --topic.pushcrew.hits=activity-logs --max.block.ms=1000 --pager.duty.api.key=apikey --dsn=dsn
```